# Reloading ListView from Inline Class

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm stuck trying to reload the `ListView` inside of a `ListFragment`. The refresh is called via a listener I've created in a `FragmentDialog`. The *reloadItems* method is properly called and I've verified that the list of items are correctly updated in the variables.

This seems like a straight forward thing to do, but I'm stuck. The ListView never actually updates, but I believe it has to do with the `Context` used.

`onClick` is called via a button on the `ListView` rows set using the `android:onClick` property.

**Solution**
The issue was that my tab adapter `getItem(...)` was unexpectantly being called again when the `AlertDialog` was being created and due to my poor code, it reinstantiated the tab and the refresh never happened on the visible fragment. (see original code at the end)

Once this was discovered (see accepted answer), I was able to fix it by reworking the code tab adapter to maintain references. Here is my working tab adapter for a `ViewPager` in case it's helpful to anyone.

```
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();
    private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> mClass;
        private final Bundle mArgs;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            mClass = _class;
            mArgs = _args;
        }

        public String getClassName() {
            return mClass.getName();
        }

        public Bundle getArgs() {
            return mArgs;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(Activity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.getClassName(), info.getArgs());
        mFragments.add(fragment);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

**End of solution**

**Activity**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    // unrelated code removed

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // onClick is called via a button on a list item
        MyFragment sf = (MyFragment)mTabsAdapter.getItem(0);
        sf.myClick(v, getFragmentManager());
    }
}
```

**MyFragment**

```
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {

    static final String TAG = "StatusFragment";
    private ArrayList<MyObject> mItems = null;
    AlarmDataSource datasource;
    StatusAdapter mAdapter;

    public void reloadItems(Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG, "reloadItems");

        datasource = new MyObjectDataSource(context);
        datasource.open();

        mItems = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        ArrayList<MyObject> active = (ArrayList<MyObject>)datasource.getAllEnabled();
        for (int i = 0; i < active.size(); i++) {
            MyObject next = active.get(i);
            mItems.add(next);
        }

        mAdapter = new StatusAdapter(
                context,
                R.layout.status_list_item,
                mItems);

        // set a breakpoint and this is called when called from
        // statusOptionDialogClose below. Here mAdapter DOES HAVE updated items
        // inside. However getView within the adaper is NOT called
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        datasource.close();
    }

    public void myClick(View v, FragmentManager manager) {
        StatusOptionDialog sod = StatusOptionDialog.newInstance(v.getContext());
        sod.setStatusOptionDialogListener(new StatusOptionDialogListener() {

            public void statusOptionDialogClose(Context context) {
                // this is correctly called when dialog closed
                // context is the same as sent in with newInstance above.
                reloadItems(context);
            }
        });
        sod.show(manager, "StatusOptionDialog");
    }
}
```

Anyone see anything awry? I've tried a ton of different ways, but nothing has worked.

*NOTE* I've also tried `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when updating and that doesn't work either. I'll try to step through the Android SDK code later on today to see if I can pinpoint data within there as well, in case the data isn't getting in to the Adapter or something odd.

**Update** I've tracked down more of the problem. It appears that after successfully calling `setListItem(mAdapter)` with a *mAdapter* that has updated items, the adapter `getView(...)` isn't called.

**Update #2** I've posted the `reloadItems(...)` function that I've distilled down to the simplest code that has the issue. `setListAdapter(...)` is called with an updated adapter that has updated items. However `getView(...)`  is never called when `reloadItems(...)` is called via `statusOptionDialogClose(...)`

If I kill the application and restart it, the ListView shows the data that was updated. Just doesn't refresh when calling reloadItems again.

**Adapter**

```
public class StatusAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyObject> {

    private Context mContext;
    private int mRes;
    private ArrayList<MyObject> mItems;

    public StatusAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<MyObject> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.mItems = items;
        this.mRes = textViewResourceId;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(mRes, null);
        }
        Alarm a = mItems.get(position);
        if (a != null) {
            // fills out list item
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    public void setNewList(ArrayList<Alarm> items) {
        this.mItems = items;
    }
}
```

**Tab Adapter** This is used to enable the `ViewPager` and tabs.

```
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(Activity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory (as others have noted) calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` should be enough, but see if calling [`ListView.invalidateViews()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#invalidateViews%28%29) after you update the data in your `setNewList()` method can force your list to display the new data (your `getView()` method should be invoked).

If `getView()` does get invoked when you force it but it still has the old data, there is a possibility that you have redundant copies of your ListFragment somehow (and the one with the updated adapter data is not visible). Maybe you will need to look into your `mTabsAdapter` implementation then.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've posted the tab adapter that I use in case it is of use. I'm not certain `getItem(...)` is implemented correctly. I've placed a breakpoint there and it is called more than expected.

Comment: You were right. The tab adapter was recreating the fragment. I reworked it and this fixed it. Wow, lots of time spent trying to figure that out. Always something stupid holding me up.

Comment: Glad to help! For what it's worth, I can tell you that I have that suspicion because I had made the same mistake myself at various time :)

Answer (score 3):

Try not to set an adapter each time, but update your adapter.

```
mAdapter.setNewList(newList);    //custom method, just replace the old list with the new one
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

That means you do not need to use `setListAdapter(mAdapter);` each time, but just the first time.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've tried that as well and it doesn't update the display. I was using `setListAdapter` as sort of a brute force way to even get the thing to update.

I like your idea with the `setNewList` method and use that within the adapter itself instead of outside and will try once I'm free later on. Any other thoughts on what may be causing it?

Comment: @Kirk I'm sorry, I do not see any problem. You have now to debug and find where is the problem. Please make sure your new list is different when you call setNewList, and the new List is setted. Then put breakpoints on your adapter's getView() and check the items are ok.

Comment: Thank you again. I'll need to step through the getView like you mention or possibly the SDK to see where it breaks down. I'll update you later on today with how it goes.

Comment: @Kirk do you use a custome adapter ?

Comment: Yes a custom adapter is used. Also, it's an ArrayList of objects that are sent in if that is any different.

Comment: Still can't find what is wrong. The `reloadItems` method is called on loading the Fragment, but refreshing later on doesn't actually update the ListView

Comment: @Kirk Try to place breakpoints / logs to see if your arrayList is well modified before calling `notifydatasetchanged`. Post your all `adapter` code and all `reloaditems()` method code, I will try to help you

Comment: I tracked it down further and `getView(...)` is never called on `notifyDataSetChanged()` / `setListAdapter(...)`. I do have `getCount()` in the adapter and is called on initial load, but never again later on when trying to reload.

Is this because I'm calling `reloadItems(...)` from within the Dialog callback and may be on a different thread?

Comment: @Kirk Please post the whole code, I need the moment where you update the list in the adapter. Your custom adapter seems ok...

Comment: I've posted the `reloadItems(...)` function that I've distilled down to the simplest code that has the issue. `setListAdapter(...)` is called with an updated adapter that has updated items. However `getView(...)`  is never called when `reloadItems(...)` is called via `statusOptionDialogClose(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Like CFlex said, you should only call `setListAdapter()` once when your `Fragment` is first created.

It looks like you are just trying to clear your list.  Typically the `Adapter` that you use will have a `clear()` method to take care of that for you which might be a little neater than completely reassigning the data object each time.  If you are using a custom `Adapter` then just override the method yourself.  Always be sure to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after you have made all your changes to the data.  This is what will cause the `ListView` to update its Views.